# Converting image to byte array and store in postgresql using function

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1

In my case, I want to store images to a Postgresql database using a stored procedure. My database is on a server.

I am converting the image into a byte array in frontend. Now O need to know how to pass the converted byte array to the stored procedure.

I am using the following code right now:

```
  Dim xImgPath() As Byte = ConverttoByte(mPath)

  Dim xQry As String = "select public.fn_employee(row(" & id &,"," & xImgPath &"))::public.employee
```

but the above piece of code is not working, it is simply displaying compile time error in the frontend. Can anybody tell me how to pass a byte array into the stored procedure in postgresql?

Comment: what's the type of the column containing the byte array?

Comment: @DavideBerra Column type is bytea

Comment: What's the compile time error say?

Answer (score 0):

First I suspect your query should read:

```
"select public.fn_employee(row(" & id &,"," & xImgPath &")::public.employee)"
```

Secondly you really should be parameterizing the query.  I am not sure the proper way to do this in .net but otherwise you risk sql injection either here or elsewhere and you make sql injection audits much harder to do.

Of course your proplem could be somewhere very different but this is the best I can do without seeing any of the errors.